# Mongoose: store base64 images processed with sharp as buffers

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to store images in mongoDB using mongoose in an express application.
The images are sent by the client from multiple places, but the things they have in common are:

- they are sent in base64 format
- they should be processed with the [sharp](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/) library
- they should be stored in a `type: Buffer` field
- when they are sent back they should be in base64 format again.

I created a separate schema** for images that I base different models on, and since the models are multiple it would be nice to have all the logic inside the schema, but I don't know how to do it.

What I tried:

- `.pre("save")` hook to convert images to `Buffer` and then process them. Fails because base64 is cast to `Buffer` from mongoose (since it's the field data type) before being processed and sharp doesn't work (it receives a wrongly encoded buffer).
- `schema.path("src").set()` to do the same thing as `pre("save")`. Fails because sharp is asynchronous and the setter is not awaiting the result (I don't know why - edit: found out async setters don't work by design).

**
`new mongoose.Schema({ src: { type: Buffer, required: true },  description: { type: String }  }, { _id: false });`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by running three separate functions in the schema.
A (synchronous) setter for the src field to correctly convert the base64 image to a Buffer without the need to make mongoose cast its value (only when the src value is a string).
A .pre("save") hook to run the async sharp task and replace the image src (it returns a Buffer so the setter should not run in this case)
A toJSON transform function to convert back the Buffer to base64 before sending it back to the client.

```
    const schema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
      description: {
        type: String,
      },
      src: {
        type: Buffer,
        required: true,
        set: (val) => {
          if (typeof val === "string") {
            const rawBase64 = val.replace(/data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
            return Buffer.from(rawBase64, "base64");
          }
          return val;
        },
      },
    },
    { _id: false }
  );
  schema.pre("save", async function (next) {
    this.src = await resizeImage(this.src);
    next();
  });
  schema.set("toJSON", {
    transform: function (doc, ret) {
      ret.src = "data:image/webp;base64," + doc.src.toString("base64");
    },
  });
```